# Can't add items to inventory <List> - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, addition

I have this problem basicaly, when I try this code `inventory.Add(database.Items[16]);` in the `Start()` function, it does add items to my inventory, but whenever I try this code on buttonClick or any other function rather than `Start()`, it's just like air, it doesn't do anything... Please for help

Inventory.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();
    public List<Item> slots = new List<Item>();

    public GameObject slotPreset;
    public GameObject parentInvetoryGridForSlots;

    public Text itemNameText;

    private ItemDatabase database;

    void Start()
    {
        database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item Database").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
        //Add item to invetory code - inventory.Add(database.Items[16]);

        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
        {
            inventory.Add(new Item());
        }

        AddItem(1);
        AddItem(2);
        AddItem(3);
        AddItem(4);


        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject spawnedSlot = Instantiate(slotPreset);
            spawnedSlot.transform.SetParent(parentInvetoryGridForSlots.gameObject.transform);

            itemNameText.text = inventory[i].itemName;
        }
    }

    void RemoveItem(int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inventory[i].itemID == id)
            {
                inventory[i] = new Item();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void AddItem(int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inventory[i].itemName == null)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < database.Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (database.Items[j].itemID == id)
                    {
                        inventory[i] = database.Items[j];
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Item Database.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();

    //Edit missing ItemType3 colors... Or wrong colors... And add missing colors to database...

    void Start()
    {
        //Wanderer Crate
        Items.Add(new Item("Bloody Combat Pants", 0, 0.12f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
        Items.Add(new Item("Blue Hi-top Trainers", 1, 2.12f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shoes, Item.ItemType3.Green));
        Items.Add(new Item("Boots (Punk)", 2, 0.19f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shoes, Item.ItemType3.Green));
        Items.Add(new Item("Cargo Pants (Beige)", 3, 0.19f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
        Items.Add(new Item("Cargo Pants (Blue)", 4, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
        Items.Add(new Item("Cargo Pants (Khaki)", 5, 0.06f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
        Items.Add(new Item("Dirty Tank-top (White)", 6, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
        Items.Add(new Item("Floral Shirt", 7, 10.19f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Glasses (Punk)", 8, 0.37f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Glasses, Item.ItemType3.Green));
        Items.Add(new Item("Hotpants (Blue)", 9, 138.12f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Purple));
        Items.Add(new Item("Long Sleeved T-shirt (Striped)", 10, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
        Items.Add(new Item("Long-sleeved T-shirt (Black)", 11, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
        Items.Add(new Item("Long-sleeved T-shirt (Light Blue)", 12, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
        Items.Add(new Item("Mandarin Jacket (Blue)", 13, 18.60f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Jacket, Item.ItemType3.Violet));
        Items.Add(new Item("Padded Jacket(Urban)", 14, 1.77f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Jacket, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Pleated Mini-skirt (Blue)", 15, 170.97f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Red));
        Items.Add(new Item("Ballistic Mask", 16, 19.02f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Mask, Item.ItemType3.Violet));
        Items.Add(new Item("Protective Glasses", 17, 45.43f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Glasses, Item.ItemType3.Purple));
        Items.Add(new Item("School Shirt (Open)", 18, 17.14f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Violet));
        Items.Add(new Item("School Shoes", 19, 17.14f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shoes, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Working Boots", 20, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shoes, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
        Items.Add(new Item("Slacks (Blue)", 21, 4.20f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("T-shirt (Red)", 22, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
        Items.Add(new Item("T-shirt (Striped)", 23, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
        Items.Add(new Item("Tank - top(Charcoal)", 24, 0.09f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Gray));
    }

}
```

Opeed Item Seel Keep.cs (In this code 'inventory.Add(database.Items[itemID]);' doesn't work)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class openedItemSellKeep : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text itemIDText;
    public Text moneyText;

    public GameObject openedCrateItemPanel;
    public GameObject backCoverPanel;

    private ItemDatabase database;

    public List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();

    public void sellItem()
    {
        database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item Database").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
        int itemID = Convert.ToInt32(itemIDText.text);
        double doubleMoney = Convert.ToDouble(File.ReadAllText("money.txt"));
        float money = ToSingle(doubleMoney);
        Debug.Log(database.Items[itemID].itemPrice);
        money += database.Items[itemID].itemPrice;
        moneyText.text = money.ToString() + "$";
        File.WriteAllText("money.txt", money.ToString());
        openedCrateItemPanel.SetActive(false);
        backCoverPanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void keepItem()
    {
        database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item Database").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
        int itemID = Convert.ToInt32(itemIDText.text);
        inventory.Add(database.Items[itemID]);
        openedCrateItemPanel.SetActive(false);
        backCoverPanel.SetActive(false);


    }

    public static float ToSingle(double value)
    {
        return (float)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a list `inventory` in both your classes `openedItemSellKeep` and `Inventory`. Unless you're setting their references equal to each other at some point, I don't see how adding to one will affect the other?

Comment: `it's just like air, it doesn't do anything` What happened when you debugged through it?

Comment: It doesn't show me anything, everything goes through smooth... What should I change then, Serlite?

Comment: As @mjwills suggested, you need to *debug your code* to identify where the problem is happening. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. If you update your question with a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** and a summary of what you tried to debug the issue, we might be in a position to help.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your functions are creating a new instance of the Inventory object. If you want a database that is accessible to multiple scripts that will always be the same instance consider making it static and global and creating it once. Also add everything to the same List. I'm assuming by your naming convention this is the inventory for a single player?

If you need multiple instances of the database for multiple players then just make it once and keep a reference for it.

One last suggestion. It looks like you are using expensive look up to retrieve info and delete items. Consider using a dictionary that uses the ID as a key and and Item as value. This way you don't have go searching 
for each item.

```
void AddItem(int id)
{        
    inventory[id] = database[id];
}

void RemoveItem(int id)
{
    inventory.Remove(id);
}
```

Comment: How do you mean that? How should I make it global and use it everywhere? Because I have no idea what you mean

Comment: You should only be doing this once. Keep a reference to the database. database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item Database").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();